# Modify and build OpenSSL source code

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.2, poodle-attack

I want to build a special version of OpenSSL that doesn't check AES CBC padding properly. I am looking into source of OpenSSL 1.0.2g. Which files in the source directory, I should look for?

I am trying to setup POODLE TLS vulnerable server, using Apache/Nginx compiled against a special version of OpenSSL that doesn't check padding properly.

Comment: Why don't you use a version of OpenSSL vulnerable to POODLE? Or, diff 1.0.2g against the vulnerable version you select? You can find past versions of OpenSSL at [Downloads | Source-Old](http://www.openssl.org/source/old/).

Comment: None of the Openssl version is vulnerable to "Poodle Tls ". Its different from Poodle sslv3 vulnerability.